# Unix/Linux and MQ scripts explaination

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, ibm-mq

```
echo "DISPLAY QL($Queue) CURDEPTH" \
    | runmqsc Queue_Managr \
    | grep 'CURDEPTH(' \
    | sed 's/.*CURDEPTH//' \
    | tr -d '()'.
```

Can anyone suggest how this script works? Actually this command displays the current depth value for a particular Q_Manager for a particular queue.

I understand `"DISPLAY QL($Queue) CURDEPTH" | runmqsc Queue_Managr"` - this command displays the queue name and curdepth{value}.

But I don't understand `grep 'CURDEPTH(' | sed 's/.*CURDEPTH//' | tr -d '()`. How does this command work?

Comment: Better start [edit]ing your post and showing a proper format. Also, have a read to [ask] for a better experience here.

Comment: @nop77svk even though your edit is good and makes the post more readable, I think it is also good to let the OP do it himself. I don't think it is very useful to prettify something that should be probably closed as "too broad" or "unclear what you are asking" since no more input was given.

Comment: @fedorqui, in general, I agree. People should learn to edit their posts. However, a user with rep of 1 might not know how a post could look like. Edits such as this one of mine can teach. Or they can't. All of that depends on OP's self reflection. It's all a _thin red line_, I'd say. I considered the question salvagable through editing, that's why I did it instead of marking it to be closed.

Comment: Saieem Ali, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33916426/edit) your question and enhance it with the results of `echo "DISPLAY QL($Queue) CURDEPTH" | runmqsc Queue_Managr`. Then we might be (better) able to help you.

Comment: @nop77svk in general, I agree : ) However I had looked at the history of this user and all his questions are like this: no good formatting, no comments, no anything.

Comment: @fedorqui, point well made. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's a pipeline.  It contains five stages, separated by the pipe character `|`.  The output of one stage is used as the input to the next stage.

- `echo "DISPLAY blatti blatti"` - this just outputs some text.
- `runmqsc Queue_Managr` - Uses the text as input to the `runmqsc`-command, which does some MQ magic and outputs data.
- `grep 'CURDEPTH('` - Grep is a standard unix utility.  It filters its input.  In this case, only lines containing the text `CURDEPTH(` is allowed through to the next stage.
- `sed 's/.*CURDEPTH//'` - Sed is another standard utility.  It's short for "stream editor", and allows you edit the input as it passes through.  In this case, the expression `'s/.*CURDEPTH//'` means to delete everything from the start of each line, up to and including the text `CURDEPTH`. (remember, only lines containing that text was passed through from the previous stage).
- `tr -d '()'` - Finally, another standard utility, tr, which also allows editing the text that flows through from input to output.  `-d '()'` means delete the characters `(` and `)` from the text.

The output from the final stage is shown in the terminal (if you ran your script in a terminal).

It's a fairly common way of building scripts in a unix shell.  Generate the input data somehow, push it to a command, and massage the output data through a couple of stages each doing its little bit.

Long dissertations can be (and probably have been) written about all of `grep`, `sed` and `tr`.  Look them up if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks Peder,it is very useful and understandable,you gave a clear point  explaination.

Comment: The `grep | sed | tr` would be better written with just `sed`; `sed -n '/CURDEPTH(/!d;s/.*CURDEPTH//;s/[()]//g;p'`

Answer (score 0):

```
   CURDEPTH(3)                     DEFBIND(OPEN)
```

Notice that there are 2 pairs of attribute-value in this output. We need to handle only the appropriate pair.

We might be tempted to use the "cut" command to do simple trimming of the first pair to get the value.

However, the output from runmqsc for queues that have very long names (such as 48 characters) shows CURDEPTH as the 2nd pair (as shown below). Thus, a simple use of "cut" is no longer possible:

```
   CRTIME(09.08.08)                CURDEPTH(3)
```

The use of the "sed" (stream editor) can help us to get the value. Notice that the parenthesis are included.

```
$ echo "DISPLAY QL($QNAME) CURDEPTH" | runmqsc $QMNAME | grep 'CURDEPTH(' | sed 's/.*CURDEPTH//'
  (3)
```

Notice that the answer is: (3)

Finally, it is necessary to remove the open and close parenthesis. This can be done using "tr" as follows:

```
$ echo "DISPLAY QL($QNAME) CURDEPTH" | runmqsc $QMNAME | grep 'CURDEPTH(' | sed 's/.*CURDEPTH//' | tr -d '()'
 3
```

Notice that the answer is: 3